# Why my geometry disappears when switching to sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting, geometry, visibility, workspaces

When I go into the sculpting tab the meshes are not visible. The only things I see is camera and light.

Layout tab:
[image: Cub is visible in layout tab]

Sculpting tab:
[image: Cube is invisible in sculpting tab]

**Q:** How to get the cube back?

Comment: What is the version of blender in your case? I check on mine version - it is ok, no such bug, default cube is visible. I have 2.81a

Comment: Try "alt + h" or press "/" on keyboard